# JS: Soundcloud API detect if song exists, despite good JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api, soundcloud

I'm using javascript to stream songs in a little web app and i get sometimes not found errors. 
I tried some suggestions I found here on SO to check existence of tracks, 
checking the json object whether is streamable or not, 
if has a title, but today i stumbled upon this track

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/111090225/stream?client_id=XXXX
```

the JSON seems good but i get error when i try to load the song audio.

so how can i prevent this issue? can I check the url directly?

Comment: can you provide a web accessible link to the track so I can test it? Thanks!